# Exclude one dimension from total count / sum in qlik

Tags: qlikview

I want to have the %-Share of a value in Qlik. I have two dimension and on KPI which I am using in a distribution graph:
[image]

The data is:

```
Point   Brand   Business
A        AA      1
B        AA      1
C        AA      1
```

Right now i am using the formula: `Count([Business])/Count(total [Business])`, on my Y-Achse I have the `Brand` and my point is `Point`, Right now he is calculating the Super total, but How can I only calculate the total for the Brand? Something like `Count([Business])/Count(total [Business], if Brand == Brand)`

Comment: try with `count([Business])/Count(total <Brand> [Business])`

Comment: it works thx, if you want post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `Brand` field as `aggregation scope`

`count([Business]) / Count(total <Brand> [Business])`

From Qlik's [documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2018/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/CounterAggregationFunctions/count.htm)

> By using TOTAL [], where the TOTAL qualifier is followed by a list of one or more field names as a subset of the chart dimension variables, you create a subset of the total possible values.

Adding the field to the total can be translated as: `count` all `Business` but aggregated by `Brand`. And since `Brand` is also a dimension to the chart then for each row `Count Total` will be the count for the current `Brand` value